# Magento admin products wont save

Tags: php, magento

Hello there and thank you for reading this.

I am in the process of trying to release a new magento system, and now the products wont save inside of the administration panel.  It is quite frustrating.  I click simple product, fill out the price description and other details, then try and save and it says please wait and never completes.

I am allowing 256 megs of ram in php, max execution time is 120 seconds.  Not sure where to start with this one, any ideas?

Comment: Your going to to have to host file redirect to see this one, 
198.61.211.252 test.sublimewellness.ca

Comment: http://test.sublimewellness.ca/store/admin   admin/admin

Answer (score 0):

You need to know if it is a never ending request or a direct KO ..

Maybe it's a javascript issue ?

- check the JS console (or install firefub on firefox) to check this
- have you enable a traduction on BO (other than standard en_US) ? Some traductions can be buffy and break some JS actions

Maybe it's a server issue ?

- with Firebug, open the "Network" tab and check the result of the save request (404 ? 503?)
- activates the Mangeto Logs (Backoffice : System / COnfiguration / Developer / Log settings) and check if you have an exception in var/log/
- if you have access to your server, check if processor is 100% occupied by a large query.

After all that you must understand where the problem comes from.
Good luck

Comment: {"error":false}0.20401811599731  thats the response from the request to /store/index.php/admin/catalog_product/validate/set/9/type/simple/key/55b2c1c90eeeba8463fe7139c5f272a5/?isAjax=true.

Comment: you must have an exception logged. Have you tried to display another Backoffice page in order to display a session error message ? I took a look at the controller app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php and it adds a error messages in the session ..

Comment: no var/log if the Log functionnality is activated (see my answer and my last comment edit)

Comment: Ok so, i enabled the loging as you requested, fine.  There is no high usage query that lags the system from linux top. Does not seem like the folder you indicated is created in the tmp dir (im on ubuntu) or in the var dir like your saying.

Comment: If you have a JSON error : you have an exception : a bug. Not an never ending query.. the log folder is in the var folder at the root of your magento installation

Comment: Right, and as I said there is nothing there by that name, i have cache, locks, package, report, and session. :).

Comment: add yourself some customs logs in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php` with the command : `Mage::log('whatever string you want');` More particularly add some in the catch block of the `validateAction` function

Comment: Just to note, in case somebody else looks at this some time.. on ubuntu magento likes to cache and store its log files and other /var folder stuff inside of /tmp/magento/var.  This is where I found the log file.  This is not a javascript issue, this is a problem with the attributes not being correct, fires at approx line 500 on this line if (array_key_exists($attrKey, $productData) && $productData[$attrKey] != ''){.. i imagine this is because I cleared my products and attributes earlier this month and forgot I had done this.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/import-export_and_data_manipulation/removing_products_through_the_database  I followed this howto.. I am going to do it again now and see if this corrects.  EDIT: Ok so I followed this, and it still does not seem to correctly work, i had to disable foreign key constraints to eeven get this howto to follow.. is there an easier way to reset this stuff? I just want to remove all products, all categories, all customers etc, back to a clean setup that migth accept products without error? :)

Comment: ok so i got it reset using the same tutorial, i no longer get those errors, but alas the problem still exists.  (this makes sense because the other errors were just warnings) that I thought might have been damaging the expected flow.  The post does not seem to happen, is this possibly an htaccess problem? im gonig to revert and try a few more things.. but from what i have for logging atm, validate is completing successfully, its just not going on from there...

Comment: What about a complete re-install ? delete all tables of DB, delete the app/etc/local.xml file and run install.php (carefull : ALL will be wiped out)